# How to store calendar app data in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, calendar, indexing

I'm creating an online Calendar app (like Google Calendar or MS Outlook), and **not sure how I should store the data** to make it fast to query for the basic views: Daily, Weekly, Monthly.

Before you mark this as a duplicate, please keep in mind I have read several threads here and in most cases they say "too hard to optimize for general purposes".  In my case this is a very specific purpose that I haven't seen asked about yet -- a very specific type of data which many developers have [hopefully] had experience with.

I need to quickly get any rows that land inside my view (day, week, month), so something like:

```
[end date of row] >= [start date of query]
AND
[start date of row] <= [end date of query]
```

I don't see a normal b-tree index working well for this, but I also suspect someone has figured out something clever that will work with SQL Server 2005 (and probably older), since calendar apps have been around forever, and there are 100s of them.

I'm also curious about reoccurring events, how to store those, although my current plan is to just always read all of those (index by "Is Recurring") and optimize that in code, and not SQL. There shouldn't be a huge number of those, unlike normal events which could get very large over time.

**Update**: Also unique to this question, because it is for a calendar app, I need to store dates with timezone info, but my queries cannot be timezone specific.  If you have experience with a Calendar app, you'll know what I mean (if not, you'll just say store as UTC).

Comment: Thanks for the edits Marc.  I still can't get over "SQL Server" being specific to Microsoft, but I guess that is the industry standard, so I'll try to remember to drop the MS/Microsoft part from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to work with something similar to this a while back.  It was emergency room software and we had to do a lot of date range and shift calculations and couldn't have time zone issues affect us.  What we ended up having to do is store 6 columns for each date.  A set three columns (Date, Date as int, and time as int) once as entered and once as UTC.  All calculations are done using UTC to avoid timezone issues.  You could also add in a timezone column if needed.

```
Date as datetime -- in the time zone entered - Used for display
UDate as a datetime -- The UTC version of the date.
            -- Used for display and some calculations
IntDate as int -- Date as an int YYYYMMDD so 20130417
IntUDate as int -- UTC date as an int.   
IntTime as int -- Time as an int HHMMSS.  
              -- So for 1:12:40 PM it would be 131240 and for 1:12:40 AM 
              -- it would be 11240.  Note only 5 places.
              -- May need to be decimal if you need more precision)
IntUTime as int -- Sames as IntTime but for the UTC datetime
```

You may not need the time columns.  We did because of the shift calculations.  Create indexes on the columns as needed.  At least the IntDate and IntUDate columns.  Because these are integers the indexes will be blazing fast.  Note that all calculations should be done using the UTC columns to avoid timezone issues.  Displays are done typically with the Date column.

Next create a date table.  What you have to realize here is that this table is fairly narrow and you can fill in hundreds of years worth of dates and still not have that large a table.  Aprox 36525 rows per 100 years.  Add in indexes and again it's very fast.

Ours looked something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE DateTable (
    [Date] Int PRIMARY KEY,
    [DayOfYear] smallint,
    [Month] tinyint,
    [Quarter] tinyint,
    [Year] smallint,
    [LeapYear] bit,
    [DaylightSavings] bit
    )
```

With indexes on (Year, DayOfYear), (Year, Month, Day) etc.  Whatever you need.  Also you can add any other columns you need.  Say leap year, holidays, first day of the month, last day of the month etc.

if you need to pull say everything for a given year/quarter you add a join on the datetable and everything is nicely indexed.

Using the example you have above you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM DateTable
    WHERE DateTable.[Date] BETWEEN MyTable.UTCStartDate AND MyTable.UTCEndDate
    AND DateTable.[Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a lot of things to think about.  Will get back to this once I have time.  I think this still suffers from the basic b-tree issue explained at the top of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947792/1042232, as far as the query speed goes, but using int over datetime does likely make it faster, and also your join idea does make it easier for ranges.  Do you have any profile info on this for large datasets?  If not, I'll run some tests, just curious.

Comment: Hopefully you have figured out how to handle timezone shifts.  For example, if the timezone rules for a Date (the one stored in users timezone) change, then you probably need to update the UDate, since it is no longer the same UTC time.  That is, unless you want "8am PST" to "shift" when rules change, so that it is still the same UTC time (but now is no longer "8am PST"), probably not what your end-users want.  Seems like a pain having to keep UDates updated (mass db update) anytime rules change, but I guess probably not a better way to handle that.

Comment: UTC doesn't change, at least not currently, and not based on time zones.  Basically UTC completly ignores time zone.  It's closely related to GMT.  Here is the wiki definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time.  We used GetUTCDate() to load the column so we didn't have to worry about the time zone on the system.  Using UTC you can do calculations regardless of time zone rule changes or daylight savings etc.  That's its purpose.

Comment: Correct, but in your design I think you are saying this (for example).  "8am PST Apr 18 2015" = some UTC time.  That calculation can change over time, if the timezone rules change.  Doesn't happen often if you only care about US, but in some countries they can change yearly.  At any rate, accepting this answer now because after profiling it will be fast enough for my needs, and nicely addresses the main requirements.  I think this timezone shift issue is already covered in other SO answers.

Comment: I am glad it helped.  I think you are looking at the whole UTC thing backwards though.  UTC doesn't shift.  The timezone date may and should be considered "display only".  If the timezone calculation changes then the timezone version may be off of what it was when it was entered.  The UTC version should still be the same.  At that point when you are displaying the timezone date you have two choices.  Display the date/time as it was originally entered, or calculate it from UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Because I think the timezone issue is important to calendar applications, and several existing applications do not handle this well (even Outlook, prior to 2007), I'm adding this info as an answer, and as follow-up to the prior comments.

I hope the Google developers will also read this, because based on http://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918?hl=en, it seems they also have the "shift" issue.  Here is what they say, which seems wrong/unacceptable to me:

> However, this process doesn't always work in cases where a country
>   decides to change when they switch to DST or even their overall time
>   zone. If you had created an event before we knew about the change,
>   Calendar converted your time zone into UTC, using the information
>   available at the time of creation. Once the time zone change is known,
>   Calendar will use the new rule to display events in your time zone,
>   and it **might cause events to shift in your calendar**.

The last part in bold is what should NEVER happen.  If I set a meeting for 8am PST, it will be at 8am PST, it will not "shift" just because some timezone rules change.

In a calendar applications, if a user enters an event for "April 26, 2020, 12:00pm, Arizona Time".  If you convert this to UTC for storage, as most applications do, you will be saving that as (with the rules at the time of me typing ths) "April 26, 2020, 7:00pm, UTC".

Then, if you want to do a query to find out if there are any events happening at "April 26, 2020, 12:00pm, Arizona Time", you would query for "April 26, 2020, 7:00pm, UTC", because that is what the current conversion rules tell you to do.

At first you would find the item, correct, yeah.

Now, if the Timezone rules change, say in the year 2018 Arizona becomes -0800 UTC instead of -0700 UTC (maybe they decide to support DST, who knows).  Then you do your query again, looking for any events happening at "April 26, 2020, 12:00pm, Arizona Time".  This time, when you do the query, you are going to look for "April 26, 2020, 8:00pm, UTC".  This is because you only know to use the current rules when you do your query, you don't know that some of your data used an older rule when it was saved.  **So you don't find the item, even though you should have, and the user misses the event.**

Now, how you decide to display that item is different from app to app, but for a calendar/schedule app it should never change the time from what the user entered.  It should still be displayed as "April 26, 2020, 12:00pm, Arizona Time" when the user views it.  However, the UTC value you use to base your queries on, doesn't match that time, because of the rules change.

The way a good calendar app should handle this (from what I've learned after much research) is:

1. Store the following info for each time entered by the user:

The Time Zone (in Windows I use the Windows Time Zone ID, but this can come from other sources, so long as it is unique and is what you use to do your conversions with).

Date and Time as entered by the user

Date and Time converted to UTC using the rules at the time the user entered the info (problem area)

1. Anytime Time Zone rules change, make sure your conversion code is updated (i.e.-Windows Updates, library update, etc), AND **within the same update process**, update all UTC times in your database using the new rules.

The "update" process is something like this:

1. Query for all records with the Time Zone that changed.  Can filter for records that have a date after the rules change if you want, since any before that have not changed (this would be based on the date as the user entered it, not the UTC value).
2. For each of those records (doesn't matter if you didn't filter exactly, or even if you just blinding do this for every record in the DB in every time zone)... run the same conversion code you did when the record was added/edited last, just take the value the user entered and convert it to UTC using the current rules, and save that new UTC value.

The **proof** that this mess is required is that the results will be that some of your UTC values **have** changed, and none of the values the user entered have changed (because we can't allow that, that would be silly for a calendar app, unless the event time was UTC based, in which case the user should have set the timezone to UTC when they added it).

Think about what happens if you don't do this update process.  All of the queries you do based on UTC are incorrect.  How could they not be?